# Nodejs Cannot GET /helloworld in simple application

Tags: javascript, node.js

This below code is my first `Express` restfull application. After running `server.js` I expected after entering `http://localhost:3020/helloworld` url on FireFox I get `Hello, World!` message, but I get this message:

```
Cannot GET /helloworld
```

code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3020;

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/helloworld', function(req, res) {
    res.render('helloworld', { title: 'Hello, World!' });
});

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});
```

Comment: Express router documentation - http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are defining the route on the router, not on the app.

```
var router = express.Router();
```

is a router, different than app.

```
var app = express();
```

What you are doing wrong, is you are not mounting the router on the app where the `/helloworld` route is defined.

do either of the following:

```
app.get('/helloworld', function(req, res) {
    res.render('helloworld', { title: 'Hello, World!' });
});
```

Or else add the following line in your app:

```
app.use('/',router);
```

Comment: after that and entering url i get this error: `Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (/var/www/signal/nodeJs/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:48:42)` i changed `render` to `console.log("dddddddd");`

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy.. you need to specify the `view engine`, which templates you are going to use. read `view engine` on http://expressjs.com/

Comment: yes, but i dont need to any view, i want to only echo simple message on console as json format message, how can i change the my route?

Comment: then remove the `res.render`. and simply send json data as `res.send({key:'value'})`, res.render is used to render some views only